# Week of year list and start from monday of week in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can find Year of Week from financial year as mention below list in SQL Server input is year and week should be start from Monday:

```
 - 01-Wk        Mar-28-Apr-03       28/03/2016   - 03/04/2016
 - 02-Wk        Apr-04-Apr-10       04/04/2016   - 10/04/2016
 - 03-Wk        Apr-11-Apr-17       11/04/2016   - 17/04/2016
 - 04-Wk        Apr-18-Apr-24       18/04/2016   - 24/04/2016
 - 05-Wk        Apr-25-May-01       25/04/2016   - 01/05/2016
 - 06-Wk        May-02-May-08       02/05/2016   - 08/05/2016
 - 07-Wk        May-09-May-15       09/05/2016   - 15/05/2016
```

Comment: I would suggest reading the 'How To Ask A Question' section http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first. Then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The best and most reliable way of doing this would be to create a calendar table. This is a table that will contain all of the information that you would need with regards to dates that can be linked to by any queries. The advantage of this is that you can set your own week numbers exactly how you need, you can also have a column for the week start date for every row of data.

A really basic version would be something like this;

```
Date         WeekNum   WeekStart   WeekEnd     Year
2016-06-01   24        2016-05-30  2016-06-05  2016
2016-06-02   24        2016-05-30  2016-06-05  2016
2016-06-03   24        2016-05-30  2016-06-05  2016 
2016-06-04   24        2016-05-30  2016-06-05  2016
2016-06-05   24        2016-05-30  2016-06-05  2016
2016-06-06   25        2016-06-06  2016-06-05  2016
2016-06-07   25        2016-06-06  2016-06-05  2016
```

This is better for performance than calculating it each time also.

Edited answer to include your comment. To retrieve your data you'd want something like this assuming you're going to pass through year and week

```
DECLARE @YearParam int; SET @YearParam = 2016
DECLARE @WeekParam int; SET @WeekParam = 24

SELECT DISTINCT
Year
,WeekNum
,WeekStart + ' - ' + WeekEnd
FROM DateTable
WHERE Year = @YearParam
AND WeekNum = @WeekParam
```

There's some further reading below around this subject;

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

http://michaelmorley.name/how-to/create-date-dimension-table-in-sql-server

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74957/best-approach-for-populating-date-dimension-table

Comment: ** But i have only year input when i input the 2016 than required result as 53 week from financial year wise like 28/03/2016   - 03/04/2016

Comment: I've just edited my answer, take a look and let me know if it gives you what you're after